# pdcurses creating the library for visual studio 2010 fails (cannot access)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pdcurses

I'm trying to create the library file for pdcurses but unfortunately I have absolutely no idea where to begin. If you could provide some steps for this it would be fantastic.

I'm using windows 8.1 if that changes anything

update

I got it working but now it is failing on cannot access complier made file insch.obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Launch a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt.  This sets your
   environment properly, so that nmake.exe is in your PATH on Windows.
2. Next, "cd" into the "win32" subfolder that was created when you extracted the compressed tar distribution of PDCurses3.4.
3. Now, you are ready to build PDCurses using Visual Studio's compiler using this command:

To perform a "clean" build target:

```
nmake -f vcwin32.mak DEBUG=Y DLL=Y WIDE=Y UTF8=Y clean
```

To build PDCurses in "DEBUG" mode (so that you can step through code in Visual Studio) with "WIDE" and "UTF8" enabled:

```
nmake -f vcwin32.mak DEBUG=Y DLL=Y WIDE=Y UTF8=Y all
```